# Not able to import FirebaseRecyclerOptions class even after important firebaseui

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Hey so I want to fetch data from firebase and put it into recycleView

```java
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<tasksClass> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<tasksClass>()
                        .setQuery(query, tasksClass.class)
                        .build();
```

I have implemented
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.4.0' in build gradle

Now I want to import class of `FirebaseRecyclerOptions but I'm not getting any option to import that class in andriod studio

Answer (score 0):

Issue is solved I just had to use latest versionof FIrebaseui